# Multiple images array javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, arrays

Ok so this is what im trying to do. By clicking a button either called "Next" or "Previous" I want to be able to change between multiple images (32 different ones) using an array in JavaScript. Keep in mind that I've only been programming for a week so I'm relatively new at this so any help would be much appreciated. This is what I've come up with so far.

```js
var images = ["myImages/dc.png", nep.jpg, ];
var index = 0;

function pressedNext() {
  if (index == 2) index = 0
  else index++;
  document.getElementById("myImage").src = images[index];
}

function pressedPrevious() {
  if (index == 0) index = 2
  else index--;
  document.getElementById("myImage").src = images[index];
}
```

Comment: Don't post it as a comment. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53486211/edit) your question and add it there.

Comment: It doesn't work it just says that I've put in code that is not properly formatted even though im using the CTRL + K commando